# $\log_x(y)=m^4$ and $\log_y(x)=5/(m^3)$, what is the value of $m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_x(y)=m^4$ and $\log_y(x)=5/(m^3)$, what is the value of $m$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\log_a b = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Another Hint:**

$$\log_x{y}=\frac{1}{\log_y{x}}$$

The above is equivalent to the hint provided by Stahl.

Answer (score 0):

stahl and response wrote almost full answer so I'll just add final steps:
$log_x(y)=m^4,log_y(x)=\frac 5 {m^3}\rightarrow m^4=log_x(y)=\frac {log_y y}{log_y x}=\frac 1 {\frac 5 {m^3}}=\frac {m^3} {5}$ and from here that's clear that $m^3=5m^4 \rightarrow m^3(5m-1)=0$ which means that the solutions are: $m=0,\frac 1 5$

### EDIT:

as adriano noted, since $log_y(x)=\frac 5 {m^3}$ we reject $m=0$ so the final solution is $m=\frac 1 5$

Comment: Note that, due to the fraction $\dfrac{5}{m^3}$, we reject the first solution and conclude that $m=\dfrac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Edited the answer. thanks.